# How to login users using ajax and php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, authentication

I've added an ajax jquery function to do a much nicer login, but it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

form_log.php withing heads:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').submit(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'login.php',
            data: {
                username: $("#username").val(), //id
                password: $("#password").val()
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                if (data === 'Correct') {
                    window.location.replace('index.php');
                }
                else {
                    alert(data);
                }
            }
        });

    });

});
</script>
```

And the  in form_log.php's html bodies:

```
    <form id="myform">

    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" value="waqmaz@gmail.com" />

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="text" id="password" value="Lol123" />

    <input type="submit" id="login" value="Login"/>

</form>
```

Now login.php:

```
    <?php
session_start();
require("funkcje_bazy.php");
//require('fff.php');

$lacz = lacz_bd();

        $nazwa_uz_l = $_POST['username'];//nazwa_uz_l
        $haslo_l = $_POST['password']; //haslo_l

        $wynik = $lacz->query("SELECT * FROM uzytkownicy WHERE  email='".$nazwa_uz_l."' AND haslo = '".$haslo_l."' AND aktywacja IS NULL ");            

        if($wynik->num_rows>0) {
            $_SESSION['prawid_uzyt'] = $nazwa_uz_l;
            echo ('Correct');
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo 'Incorrect username/password';
        }

?>
```

At the top of all these 2 files I have session_start(); icluding index.php.

The login doesn't work. When I click input submit, nothing happens. I am new to an jquery ajax. I check the correct answers, thanks.

Comment: Any errors on console..?

Comment: There are no erros on console.

Comment: what is the value of data inside of the success callBack..?

Comment: I do not understand. My data is: data: {
                username: $("#username").val(), //id
                password: $("#password").val()
            }, I put a waqmaz@gmail.com to an input username and Lol123 to password.

Comment: Have you included your javascript library (jQuery, for example) in your HTML header?

Comment: What Rajaprabhu means is what does your PHP actually echo when it fires. Have you tested rather than trying to debug the JS because you may have an error in your PHP where nothing is being returned.

Comment: It was about e.preventdefault. I missed it. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to prevent the default action of the `submit` button by using `event.preventDefault()`, meaning block the post back which is about to happen,

```
 $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   .
   .

 //rest of your code.
```

Comment: Wow, it works! Thank You so much. Why do I need to prevent default?

Comment: @glapa.wojciech Because we are going to do postback via ajax, if we don't prevent the default action, the form get submitted, as a consequence page will get reloaded.. And by the way, glad to help..!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use:

```
 $('#login').click(function() {
```